# Prevent angular from parsing {{ in template

Tags: angular

Is there a solution to force angular not to parse `{{ }}` ?
I want to put some angular code i html template but angular is trying to parse it.

`<![CDATA[ {{index}} ]]>` - that is not working with `aot`

Comment: Quote it with `''` like this - `<![CDATA[ `{{index}}` ]]>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `ngNonBindable`

https://codecraft.tv/courses/angular/built-in-directives/ngnonbindable

```
<span ngNonBindable> {{index}} </span>
```

Or you could also have a variable containing the text with curly braces

**component.ts**

```
public stringWithBraces = "{{index}}";
```

**component.html**

```
{{stringWithBraces}}
```

Or you could use quotes (but it's not very readable)

```
 {{ '{{' }}index  }}
```

[Stackblitz demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-zorf3s?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)

Comment: Thanks. I was looking for `ngNonBindable`